# Data loss and misplaced values after Append

Tags: arcgis-desktop, append

I attempted to append 10 shapefiles after carefully verifying the schema. I keep losing large amount of data and getting misplaced values (in wrong columns/fields).

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and total appended dataset size is 2mill plus observations (parcel polygons and attribute data).

Any ideas of what could be happening? I double/tripled check the schema in all 10 files.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles have a size limit of 2GB. Perhaps your dataset is larger than the limit, therefore not everything is copying over. Try working in a file geodatabase, appending the shapefiles into a feature class.